# Check if that sentence is grammatically correct

Tags: grammaticality

Why is *thinking of* used instead of *think of*, in the following sentence?

> People talk and listen to what **others thinking of** and learn.

It is taken from [Youtube](https://youtu.be/X1i6dT-GWkE?t=31), at the end of paragraph 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an error.  It should be "what others are thinking of".

This is from an essay written for an IELTS test and contains numerous small errors and odd phrases ("thinking about" would be better, for example).  It suggests that it is actual student work, written by an English learner. It is not meant to be an example of correct English, but to demonstrate the type of content that you write in the large text area in the computer-delivered test.